# rails - map through activerecord relation in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an `edit.html.erb` file with a `form_for` defined like this:

`<%= form_for @text_message, url: text_message_path(@text_message) do |f| %>`

At the bottom of the html file, I have javascript code that looks like this:

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
  setInitialUserSegments();
});



function setInitialUserSegments(){

<%= @text_message.text_message_segments.map do |segment| %>

    createUserSegment('<%= segment.segment_type %>', '<%= segment.segment %>')

  <% end %>
}


</script>

<% end %>
```

I need to go through each `text_message_segment` of the `@text_message` object and pass parameters to the `createUserSegment` method; however, it fails with the following error in the console...

`edit:619 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`

When I navigate into the error, it shows this:

```
function setInitialUserSegments(){

   createUserSegment('test', 'lol')

  [&quot;&#39;)\n\n&quot;]
}
```

How can I go through each `text_message_segment` of the `@text_message` in my javascript and call the method without getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> [&quot;&#39;)\n\n&quot;]
> ```

This is returned by `map` and `<%= %>` prints the result

**Solution**

```
<% @text_message.text_message_segments.each do |segment| %>
  createUserSegment('<%= segment.segment_type %>', '<%= segment.segment %>')
<% end %>
```

**Replace**

1. `<%= %>` with `<% %>` and
2. `map` with `each` (not mandatory but since you don't need the result you can use each)

**The reason:**

1. `<%= %>` prints the result of the operation
   and
2. `map` returns you an array

Comment: Appreciate you!